# Move progress bar from left to right in cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: c++, progress-bar, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using the following code to make a progress bar in cocos2d-x 3.2.

```
Sprite *fuelBarBorder;

fuelBarBorder = CCSprite::create("ui_kbg.png");

fuelBarBorder->setPosition(_visibleSize.width/2,_visibleSize.height/2);

this->addChild(fuelBarBorder, 1);


CCProgressTimer *fuelBar;
fuelBar = CCProgressTimer::create( CCSprite::create("slt_bg.png"));

// Set this progress bar object as kCCProgressTimerTypeBar (%)
fuelBar->setType(ProgressTimerType::BAR);

// Set anchor point in 0,0 and add it as a child to our border sprite
fuelBar->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 0));

fuelBar->setBarChangeRate(ccp(1, 0)); // To make width 100% always
fuelBar->setTag(1);                  // Tag our object for easy access

fuelBarBorder->addChild(fuelBar, 50); // Add it inside the border sprite
```

Issue is bar in moving from center to both directions (i.e L and R), I want to move it in LR direction, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fuelBar->setMidpoint(Vec2(0.0f, 0.1f));` for LR direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look at the cocos2d-x Gui Widget
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/cocos2d-x/en/ui_components/loading_bar.html

A much easier approach to this

Edit 1:
header

```
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"
using namespace cocos2d::ui;
```

in the init

```
LoadingBar* loadingBar = LoadingBar::create();
loadingBar->setName("LoadingBar");
loadingBar->loadTexture("cocosgui/sliderProgress.png");
loadingBar->setPercent(0);
loadingBar->setPosition(Point(widgetSize.width / 2.0f, widgetSize.height / 2.0f +     loadingBar->getSize().height / 4.0f));
m_pUiLayer->addChild(loadingBar);
this->schedule(schedule_selector(Scene::UpdateProgress),0.025f);
```

then in the call back function

```
void Scene::UpdateProgress(float dt)
{
counter++;
if (counter > 100)
{
    this->scheduleOnce( schedule_selector( Scene::GoToScene ), 0 );

    unschedule(schedule_selector(Scene::UpdateProgress));
}
loadingBar->setPercent(counter);
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example which shows in which way it is easier?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg There you go, edited the previous post with an example.. its already in  the wiki though